# Eloquent group messages

Tags: sql, eloquent

I´m playing with Laravel´s eloquent and a MYSQL database

I need to display a list of conversations
this is my table structure

```
messages:
- id
- from_id
- to_id
- message
- read

|----|-----------|---------|-------|------|
| id | message   | from_id | to_id | read |  
|----|---------------------|--------------|
| 1  | hello     | 1       | 2     | 1    |
| 2  | hey       | 2       | 1     | 0    |
| 3  | there     | 2       | 1     | 0    |
| 4  | hi!       | 3       | 1     | 1    |
|----|-----------|---------|-------|------|

users:
- id
- name

|-----------|
| id | name |  
|-----------|
| 1  | john |
| 2  | mary | 
| 3  | jack | 
|-----------|
```

expected:

if I´m user 1 (it should show me the last message and the count of unread

```
|----|------|---------|--------|
| id | name | message | unread |  
|----|------|---------|--------|
| 3  | mary | there   | 2      |  
| 4  | jack | hi!     | 0      |   
|----|------|-------- |--------|
```

I´m not sure if this is the right table structure for what I want to do but the SQL should be something like

```
SELECT users.name, messages.message
FROM users, messages
WHERE messages.from_id = 1 OR messages.to_id = 1
GROUP BY ??
ORDER BY messages.id DESC
```

I´m not sure how to GROUP because if I group by messages.from_id = 1 it will only show messages I sent and not messages I received. please help me thing :)

also how to handle the read status? for sure that read attribute is something like the to_id will set to 1. how to check that in the query as well?

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results as tabular text.

Comment: yes absolutely. that makes it easier. done! thanks

Answer (score 0):

THere's a couple of things I see here.
1. while aggregating your data to count the number of unread emails, you are still showing at least one message which indicates message text.  In the expected response:

```
|----|------|---------|--------|
| id | name | message | unread |  
|----|------|---------|--------|
| 3  | mary | there   | 2      |  
| 4  | jack | hi!     | 0      |   
|----|------|-------- |--------|
```

You have two unread messages for mary, however the message column says `there`, which is only the message of one the two unread emails.
I'm just wondering if that's on purpose.

However,  to get you where you need to go,
you have the `read` column which appears binary in nature:  1 for messages read, 0 for messages not read.

That being said, you can utilize that logic to count the number of unread messages by using the algorithm: `count(read) - sum(read)`.

2. the second thing is your joins.  You have to join the tables together in order to establish names to user_ids.  in your case, you are not using a join at all but filtering by field.  if you want a list of `from` users, filtered by the `to` users, then you need to join the `from_id` to the `user_id` so you can get the name.

There you can group by name and at least get `id, name, unread`.  as forth in this example:

```
SELECT users.name, count(read) - sum(read) as unread
FROM users, messages
WHERE users.id = messages.from_id and messages.to_id = 1 --to me
GROUP BY users.name
ORDER BY messages.from_id ASC
```

in laravel ORM, try this (I know I"m close, but I'm mobile and haven't been able to test it, so play around):

```
$users = DB::table('messages')
                 ->select(DB::raw('users.name, count(read) - sum(read) as unread'))

                 ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'messages.from_id')
                 ->where('to_id', '=', 1)
                 ->orWhere('from_id', '=', '1')
                 ->groupBy('users.name')
                 ->orderBy('messages.from_id','ASC')
                 ->get();
```

Try this.

### UPDATE 1:

to purposely get the "latest" message with the list:

```
select u.name, fm.message, count(m.unread) - sum(m.unread) as unread, 
  case when m.from_id = 1 then 'sent'
  when m.to_id = 1 then 'received'
  else null
  end status
from messages m
join users u on u.id = m.from_id
left join (
    Select max(id) as id, from_id, message from messages group by from_id
) fm on m.from_id = fm.from_id
where m.from_id = 1 or m.to_id = 1
group by u.name;
```

Eloquent:

```
DB::table('messages')
    ->select('u.name', 'fm.message', 'count(m.read) - sum(m.read) as unread', 'case when m.from_id = 1 then "sent" when m.to_id = 1 then "received" else null end status')
    ->join(users u', 'u.id', '=', 'u.from_id')
    ->leftjoin(DB::raw('Select max(id) as id, from_id, message from messages group by from_id', 'm.from_id', 'fm.from_id'))
    ->groupBy('users.name')
    ->orderBy('messages.from_id','ASC')
    ->get();
```

Comment: correct. that's on purpose. I dea is to show only the last unread message but a count of total unread messages. trying your approach know. appreciate that :)

Comment: hello. if I´m user with id 1 and send a message to user id 2 i should be able to see that conversation as well. in my list of conversations.  and according to your code is only looking at to_id field

Comment: ok.  using SQL FIDDLE http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a50e7f/13, I've given an update to above.  Hopefully this will work for you.

Comment: of note, whill eloquent is eloquent :).....there does come a time when DB::RAW becomes your best friend.  food for thought.

Comment: hi! i played ith your fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46e6a5/1/0 and changed the data to emulate that user 1 sent a message to user 2 and user 2 replied to 1. when I run the query I see two records. i should only see one. the last message from the conersation between user 1 and user 2. how to fix that?